# Target integrity - mac os deployment target newer than sdk warning

Tags: iphone, xcode

i was add a new target in my existing project.
Everything work fine, but... this warning is become.
Mac OS X Deployment Target '10.6' is newer than SDK 'iOS 4.2' in target snow iphone
Anybody knows how i can disable it?

Answer (score 3):

XCode4 is different and I had trouble finding this option.  Here is how to do it - to access the Base SDK for the project, select the project (blue xcode icon) in the navigator top-left; select project properties (not targets) in the next pane; then select "Build Settings".

I tried to post a screenshot but apparently I need to earn more "reputation points" first...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I ran across the same issue and want to provide help. The warning means your version of Xcode is using an SDK older than your deployment target. For example, you have Xcode 6.2 but are deploying for iOS 8.3. You would need to update Xcode to version 6.3 to resolve that error. Another option is to simply download the SDK manually from the Apple Developer center.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your target and select `Get Info`.  Go to the `Build` tab and ensure that the `Base SDK` setting is `Latest iOS`.

Answer (score 0):

go to target settings and make sure that Base SDK is set to the latest one. Also check the deployment target.

Comment: BaseSDK : Latest iOS (iOS 4.2)

Comment: iOs deployment target: iOS 4.2

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem when I accidentally opened my older version of Xcode. If you have 2 versions of Xcode installed on your computer, make sure you are using the one you intend to! The older version won't understand a newer deployment SDK.